# Prevent button with click event inside div with mouseover event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a div with a **mouseenter** event. Within that div there is a button with a click event. The idea is that the user hovers over the div, on the **mouseenter** event, the div becomes "active". If the div is active, then the button is visible and clickable.

Everything seems to work great on desktop. However, on mobile, due to the **mouseenter** event, if you click where the button should become visible, on an inactive div, the button is clicked.

I'd like to prevent the user from accidentally clicking the button when they think they're clicking the div to make it "active". I'm assuming this can be done with event handling https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers but I cannot for the life of me work it out.

Please see the following codepen - https://codepen.io/jameshine/pen/GRNNzdq or code below.

**Please note: If you test on desktop and click the button, you will still get the "clicked by mistake" error message. This codepen is for mobile view, but I'm unsure I can force it to display my problem in mobile?**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="flex -mx-2">
      <div class="w-1/2 px-2" @mouseenter="activate(key)" v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key">
        <div class="h-full p-5 rounded-lg" :class="[ active === key ? 'bg-yellow-500' : 'bg-gray-300']">
          <div class="mb-10">
            <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
          </div>

          <button class="bg-red-500 px-3 py-2 rounded" @click="alert('I\'ve been clicked by mistake')" v-if="active === key">Activate Me</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
    return {
      active: undefined,
      items: [
        {
          name: "A"
        },
        {
          name: "B"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    activate(key) {
      this.active = key;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you need to do something like this:

```
<button @click.prevent.stop="handleClick(key)">Activate me</button>

// Methods:
handleClick(key) {
  if (this.active !== key) {
    this.active = key;
  } else {
    // Do whatever the button should do here
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The issue seems to be with the `mouseenter` event firing immediately before the `click` event on mobile. This seems a bit hacky but I think it should work - if you had a slight delay inside your `activate` method, like this:

```
activate(key) {
  setTimeout(() => this.active = key, 50);
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's an alternative solution - add this to your parent div:

`@touchstart.prevent="handleTouchStart($event, key)"`

Then in your methods:

```
handleTouchStart($event, key) {
  if (this.active === key) {
    $event.target.click();
  } else {
    this.active = key;
  }
}
```

What this does is, when a `touchStart` event is registered on the parent div, if it is not currently "active", the event is cancelled but the div is made active. If it is currently active, it allows the click event to proceed as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The button within the div isn't responsible for activating the parent div. The mouseenter event sets the div as active. The button will just emit an event, but for purposes of this example it just triggers an alert. The issue, from what I can see, is that the mouseenter event is triggering correctly, but oddly the button hidden with v-if is also being clicked, although at the time of the initial click, it shouldn't be visible. So it's as if the click is happening before the v-if is rendered.

Comment: No worries! I understand better now - I've updated my answer with a possible solution. My instinct was to use event modifiers here as well but it doesn't seem to solve the issue of how `mouseenter` fires on tap.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This works and the little delay isn't noticeable. Would there have been an alternative to @mouseenter I could've used in this scenario?

Comment: I think keep your @mouseenter event since there doesn't seem to be an alternative to get the effect you're looking for on desktop. I've added another update with a solution that doesn't involve `setTimeout`.